# Design pattern name for implementation of interface method delegating the core functionality to another method

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface, abstraction

Can happen to have a class that implements an interface like:

```
interface ICommand
{
    public function execute();
}

class deleteCommand implements ICommand
{
    public function execute() {
        if($this->validateConditions()) {
            $this->performExecute()
        } else {
            // do something else ..
        }
    }

    public function performExecute() {
        // the real code we want to execute
    }
}
```

My question is:

#### Does this pattern, of having a second method that really perform the operations supposed to stay in the interface method, has a name?

I maybe heard some term like *performExecute()* method is a *"template"*, but I'm not sure.
I guess this should be some kind of abstraction pattern.

*Can someone give a proper name to this pattern? Or maybe point me to some article/documentation?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were calling `performExecute` on a "helper" object then it would be the [Delegate Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#PHP).  Without that layer of abstraction, I think it's less of an official Design Pattern and more just normal subroutine usage.